# Whats correct UML Of Hierarchical Inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, uml

What is actual UML diagram of Hierarchical inheritance,In some of tutorials Arrows are pointing towards base class and some are pointing towards sub class.

I know  Arrows point towards Base class always.

But wondering is there any special case in Hierarchical inheritance so that some tutorial have arrows are pointing downward.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The arrow towards the destination element is mostly used when showing Interfaces. So in your example, if B is an Interface, then A is an implementation of that Interface. The same goes for C -> A and B -> A.

Comment: So, maybe that is also the case for abstract classes?

Comment: @LeonBohmann Let's assume both parent class and base class is neither an interface nor abstract,just there are normal regular classes,then which UML is correct?

Comment: Have a look at the answer below. He is pointing out that the representation of the interface should have a different style from the one you've shown.

Comment: Where did the first diagram come from? Did the site actually say it was standard compliant UML?

Answer (score 3):

As a reference you should take here the UML specification and it clearly states the generalization has an arrowhead pointing to the superclass (parent class). See Section 9.2.5. for a clear confirmation.

Both diagrams use a wrong type of arrows (it should be a solid line with a hollow triangle as an arrowhead) but in terms of direction the second one is correct assuming A is a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

The first diagram is wrong, in my opinion.

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) generalization in UML 2.5 is expressed using arrows which are pointing from subclasses to the base class.

I also think that first picture doesn't show us interface realization because

> The UML graphical representation of a Realization is a **hollow triangle**
>   shape on the interface end of the **dashed line**(or tree of lines) that
>   connects it to one or more implementers.

Someone can be very creative and will come up with a brand new standart and teach the standart in his/her tutorials, so I advise you to read something more professional. For example, it can be [UML Distilled by Martin Fowler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687).

Comment: The question is not about realization but about inheritance.